# How to sort a list of Dates and Time in dictionary?

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I have a dictionary with 3 keys and their values as a list of dates and time. I'm trying to sort the lists of dates and times from oldest to newest, but I'm not really sure how to sort them. Is there a simple way and quick way to sort these lists of date and time?

```
commits_dict = {
    'Jordan McCullough': ['2014-11-07, 18:27:19', '2014-11-05, 20:00:35', '2014-11-05, 19:59:55'],
    'Peter Bell': ['2013-06-18, 19:34:38', '2014-11-05, 15:33:57'],
    'Matthew McCullough': ['2012-08-31, 20:35:43', '2012-08-31, 00:00:50', '2012-07-25, 05:25:20']
}
```

Comment: `print({k: sorted(v) for k,v in commits_dict.item()})` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use as key the datetime value of each string, and sort from oldest to newest:

```
import datetime

commits_dict = {
    'Jordan McCullough': ['2014-11-07, 18:27:19', '2014-11-05, 20:00:35', '2014-11-05, 19:59:55'],
    'Peter Bell': ['2013-06-18, 19:34:38', '2014-11-05, 15:33:57'],
    'Matthew McCullough': ['2012-08-31, 20:35:43', '2012-08-31, 00:00:50', '2012-07-25, 05:25:20']
}


def key(s):
    return datetime.datetime.strptime(s, '%Y-%m-%d, %H:%M:%S')


result = {k: sorted(v, key=key) for k, v in commits_dict.items()}

print(result)
```

**Output**

```
{'Jordan McCullough': ['2014-11-05, 19:59:55', '2014-11-05, 20:00:35', '2014-11-07, 18:27:19'], 'Peter Bell': ['2013-06-18, 19:34:38', '2014-11-05, 15:33:57'], 'Matthew McCullough': ['2012-07-25, 05:25:20', '2012-08-31, 00:00:50', '2012-08-31, 20:35:43']}
```

Comment: @Pitto Updated the answer, just drop the reverse=True

Comment: This is working, thanks. But I have a question, what exactly does the def key(s) function do in this case?

Comment: @apson11 It converts the strings to dates and use the value as the key for sorting